# User related content - field collection / views

Tags: views, users, entities

I got a tricky situation. I'm working on Drupal 7.19 with Views 3.

I want to make a view in user profile page, that will show the user related content. Its sounds easy, but not exactly. The content is a photos, that are made as a field collection (one fields includes the image upload form, and couple text input fields). To get the latest fields from field collection data, I need to choose it as a view, and then pick all the fields I want to show.

My view with field collection fields need to be inserted as another field in parent view (its because the standard view doesn't allow you to choose the fields from field collection).

Well, at this point I managed to show the photos, but only all of them (not created by the  viewed user).

Can anybody tell me whats the solution, or just give some ideas?
In attachment you will find the screen:

The parent view:
[image: snap]

The field collection view:

[image: snap]

Comment: Can you show us the SQL queries that views are generating here?

Comment: probably I can, but how to check that? sorry, Im not an expert.

Comment: The queries that views are generating are visible at the bottom of your view edit page. In other words they would be visible in you screen shots if you would cut them a few cm lower.